# Fedora CD versions vs DVD

Tags: linux, fedora

Does the DVD version include all the interfaces (KDE/GNOME/LXDE/Xfce) witch can be fund on separate CD's?

[CD's](http://fedoraproject.org/en/get-fedora-options)

[DVD](http://fedoraproject.org/en/get-fedora-options#formats)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The DVD contains only GNOME and KDE. You can do a netinstall if you want Xfce or LXDE instead.