# How can I switch from KDE to LXDE?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kde, lxde

I want to switch from KDE to LXDE. How can I do this?

Comment: Any particular distro?

Comment: You'll have to provide at least the following information: Which distribution do you use (see above), which version of it, do you want to continue using your KDE tools or is this question also about uninstalling KDE, and what KDE functionality / data do you still need after the migration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*System > Administration > Login Screen* 
 and choose from LXDE/GNOME/...

(default is Ubuntu Desktop Edition)

Comment: If that means that you've answered your own question, you might as well select yours as the correct one so people know that it has been solved.

Comment: in 5 hours i can check it :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your [previous question](https://superuser.com/questions/234439/fedora-cd-versions-vs-dvd) indicates that you're on Fedora, then install and use `system-switch-displaymanager` to switch to GDM (installing it first if it hasn't already been), then just choose LXDE from the menu upon boot.

Comment: You will have to install lxde via the following command: yum install @lxde-desktop

Comment: Good point; I assumed from the question that he had already installed it, but on reflection, that's not obvious.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu with KDE and I want to switch when I want to LXDE/XFCE/....